# Codeigniter - query builder, left join, unprepared PHP variable in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, query-builder

May be you have some idea how I can escape `$this->lang'. 
This is my actual query:

```
$this->db->select('p.id, p.photo, p.desc, info.desc');
$this->db->from('products as p');
$this->db->join('lang_info as info', 'info.id=p.id and info.name=\'good\' info.lang='.$this->lang, 'left');
$this->db->join('lang_info as info2', 'info2.id=p.id and and info2.name=\'bad\' info2.lang='.$this->lang, 'left');
$this->db->where('p.id', $this->product_id);
```

I can't use `where` clause because I get less output rows:

```
$this->db->where('info.lang', $this->lang);
$this->db->where('info2.lang', $this->lang);
```

I need something like `$this->db->join_on('info.lang', $this->lang);` but in codeigniter I can't find something like this

Comment: Why you have added two and in your join statement? I.e 'info.id=p.id and and info.name=\'good\' info.lang='

Comment: updated :p it's example only, this code wasn't tested. I wanted to show my problem as easy as possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
$this->db->select('p.id, p.photo, p.desc, info.desc');
$this->db->from('products as p');
$this->db->join('lang_info as info', 'info.id=p.id and info.lang='.$this->lang, 'left');
$this->db->where('p.id', $this->product_id);
$this->db->where_in('info.name', ['good', 'bad']);
```